# MongoDB, create script for mongo shell

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I new to Mongodb, I tried to find good tutorials but no luck.

2 question:

1. I have mongo install with data and I want to connect it with js file and play with it
   I created a.js file and my firs two line were:

   `conn = new mongo();`

   `db = conn.getDB("table1");`

and I get error `ReferenceError: mongo is not defined at a.js`

2. any good tutorials ?

Comment: Use `db.getSiblingDb('table1')` and the second question is one left to Google

Comment: As per the error message, there is no constructor for a `mongo` object. That should instead be `conn = new Mongo()` (proper case). For more information on how to write scripts see: [Write Scripts for the mongo Shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) in the MongoDB manual.

Comment: While you can write JavaScript code that runs in the `mongo` shell, note that this is not intended as a full application programming environment. For example, you will have limited control over input & output. If you are just getting started with MongoDB you will probably find it easier to start with one of the [supported language drivers](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/) (many include tutorials, too). The free online courses at [MongoDB University](https://university.mongodb.com) are also a great start.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and it work fine:

```
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("a");
var c = db.getCollectionNames();
print(c);
```

When I run the file it print all my collection to the shell
Thanks.